# ModelCheckpoint monitoring values when the model has multiple outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

My model has two outputs, I want to monitor one to save my model.
Below is part of my code. The version of TensorFlow is 2.0

```
model = MobileNetBaseModel()()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics={"pitch_yaw_roll": "mae"},
              loss={"pitch_yaw_roll": compute_mse_loss, # or "mse"
                    "total_logits": compute_cross_entropy_loss(num_classes=num_classes)},
              loss_weights= {"pitch_yaw_roll":mse_weight, "total_logits":cross_entropy_weight})
file_path = os.path.join(checkpoint_path, "model.{epoch:2d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5")
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=file_path,
                                   monitor="val_loss",
                                   verbose=1,
                                   save_freq=save_freq,
                                   save_best_only=True)
```

The default `monitor='val_loss'` in the `ModelCheckpoint` callback, how do I choose what I need? I want to monitor `{"pitch_yaw_roll": "mae"}`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? you want to save only the epoch with the lowest `"pitch_yaw_roll"` value?

Comment: Yes, Maybe I want to save the model corresponding to the lowest value every few batches. As I described, in `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` can I only choose `monitor = val_loss`? Thanks for your help! @bluesummers

Answer (score 2):

If you want `ModelCheckpoint` to save according to another metric value, use the key of that metric in the `.compile(metrics={...}, ...)` metrics dictionary.

So for example, if you would like to save only the best `"pitch_yaw_roll"` epoch result (best being the minimum value) you should use

```py
tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=file_path,
                                   monitor="val_pitch_yaw_roll",
                                   verbose=1,
                                   mode="min",
                                   save_freq=save_freq,
                                   save_best_only=True)
```

If you opt for `"pitch_yaw_roll"` instead of `"val_pitch_yaw_roll"` it will save according to the training loss and not according to the validation loss

Comment: According to what you mean, I know how to save according to the loss, so what if I want to use the `mae` of the validation set instead of the loss of the validation set? Just like `monitor="val_picth_yaw_roll_mae`?

Comment: Like I wrote exactly, don't include the `mae` just use `val_pitch_yaw_roll` - since this key points to the `mae`, what will be monitored is the `mae`

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to comment above, I belive your checkpoint doesn't work because of incorrect name of value to monitor.
General, solution here might be to have a peak into history that your fit creates.

```
history = model.fit(...)
pd.DataFrame(history.history)
```

there you will find names of metrics you should use in monitor statement.